# Google Map API Route Request limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am working on my project in which I need to calculate distances of 23 driving routes in Google map. I have the code here. The Lat and lng are already set up in js but I only get 10 route distances back in the web. I check the limitations of google maps api but I don't see only 10 limitations for the route direction. I attached the code.... I am wondering whether anybody can help me figure out.....Thank you so much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html>
    <head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Waypoints</title>
        <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
        </script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/GTFS/style.css" media="all" />

    </head>

<body id="mainBody" onload="initialize()">
<div id="headerImage">
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/GTFS/brt.jpg" height="100" width="180" />
</div>

    <header id="mainHeader">
        <hgroup id="mainHeaderGroup">
            <h1>GTFS Data Visualization & Application</h1>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </hgroup>
    </header>
    <div id="contentContainer" >
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:0%;height:0%;">
        </div>
        <br />
        <p id="demo">
</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(-40.321, 175.54);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: chicago
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calcRoute();
    }

    function calcRoute()  {
         var locations = [
  ['location1', 30.27361,-97.69835, 4],
  ['location2', 30.273206,-97.700665, 5],
  ['location3',30.272939,-97.70225, 3],
  ['location4', 30.272556,-97.704568, 2],
    ['location5', 30.272509,-97.706226, 4],
  ['location6', 30.272329,-97.708247, 5],
  ['location7', 30.271236,-97.710649, 3],
  ['location8', 30.270419,-97.715, 2],
    ['location8', 30.270096,-97.717001, 4],
  ['location9', 30.269698,-97.719604, 5],
  ['location10', 30.269427,-97.72125, 3],
  ['location11', 30.268978,-97.724138, 2],
   ['location12', 30.270096,-97.717001, 4],
  ['location13', 30.269698,-97.719604, 5],
  ['location14', 30.269427,-97.72125, 3],
  ['location15', 30.268978,-97.724138, 2],
  ['location16', 30.268756,-97.725507, 1],
    ['location17',30.268704,-97.727634, 2],
  ['location18', 30.26956,-97.729989, 4],
  ['location19', 30.269995,-97.731193, 5],
  ['location20', 30.270893,-97.734212, 3],
  ['location21', 30.27116,-97.738825, 2],
   ['location22', 30.271811,-97.741229, 2],
  ['location23', 30.268756,-97.725507, 1]
];   

var i=0;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length - 1; i++) {
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i + 1][1], locations[i + 1][2]);
var request = {
origin : start,
destination : end,
travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request,function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
var route = response.routes[0];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<strong> <br /> <hr />"+     route.legs[0].distance.text + "</strong>";
}
});
}
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The free API has a limitation of 8 waypoints (plus the 2 endpoints give 10).  The paid API allows 23 waypoints.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints)

> The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination. Maps API for Business 
>   customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination. Waypoints are not 
>   supported for transit directions.

You can try chaining multiple requests together like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrs_busRoute.html), but beware the DirectionsService is subject to rate limits and quotas, so that might not always work.

[example with your points](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrs3.html)