# Direction service googlemap

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need some help in google maps using the direction services,.I am requesting the coordinate (lat,long) via ajax,..I have found out that if i only have 7 coordinates the direction service is working it will draw marker and line to the map,.Now if i tried to have 40 coordinates requested,it will not draw or nothing happens.my coordinates returned like this

> ["12.34343,14.324324","12.34343,14.324324","12.34343,14.324324","12.34343,14.324324","12.34343,14.324324"]

//I just put example here for the coordinates,and until it reach to 40 coordinates...this is how i done in the ajax.

```
$.ajax({
     ...
     ...
      ...
     success: function (data){
     var pts=[];
         for(var x=0;x<data.datapts.length;x++){
             waypts.push({
                 location:data.datapts[x],
                 stopover:true
             });
         }
         directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                 directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);          
             }
         }
     });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map API Route Request limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946208/google-map-api-route-request-limit/18946268#18946268).  There is a [maximum of 8 waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) in the fee API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [maximum of 8 waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) in the fee API.